# special character encoding error utf-8 iso-8859-1

Tags: jsf, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters, iso-8859-1

I'm having problems displaying special characters (like é and à) in my jsf application. These characters get displayed as a question mark or Ã©.
Therefore I tried a simple thing. I have a page with a form post to a result page displaying the posted parameters.

page 1

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:8080/test/result.xhtml" name="data"  target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" value="Pierre;DUPONT;5300;Seilles;;Rue des écoles 18;fr;;" name="customer"/>
```

page result

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body >

test

    <h:inputText value="${param.customer}"/>

</body></html>
```

The result is shown as ue des Ã©coles  in stead of ue des écoles

I'm developing in Eclipse with Text-file encoding on UTF-8 and running on tomcat 6.024

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems the meta tag is ignored and the browser is still using iso-8859-1 to view it. Have you tried sending an actual content-type header?

Comment: What view technology are you using? JSP or Facelets? The absence of `<h:head>` and `<h:body>` indicates JSP, but your question history indicates JSF2 (and thus imlicitly also Facelts as JSP is deprecated in JSF2). Note that I actually think that you're using JSP as Facelets uses by default already UTF-8. But the choice for JSP in JSF2 is very strange these days. So, just to be sure. In the future questions please always, always mention the exact JSF impl/version used and the view technology used and component libraries used, if any.

Comment: Hi, I just took some code snippets. I'm using facelets and JSF1.2 (old project with legacy code).

Comment: Ok, found out that there was still a filter changing the encoding. Sorry for interrupting.